# PassportJS + Babel: passport.initialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, babeljs

Trying to use babel-node and some new ES6 stuff to make a SPA api server. Including passport is proving to be an issue, as the `initialize()` function is failing to be found after compilation:

```
10:17:54 PM web.1 |  C:\Users\-\Desktop\bioan\server\app.js:37
10:17:54 PM web.1 |  _auth2.default.initialize(server);
10:17:54 PM web.1 |                 ^
10:17:54 PM web.1 |  TypeError: _auth2.default.initialize is not a function
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/-/Desktop/bioan/server/app.js:17:6)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at loader (C:\Users\-\Desktop\bioan\server\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:
5)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\-\Desktop\bioan\server\node_modules\babel
-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\-\Desktop\bioan\server\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:154:22)
10:17:54 PM web.1 |      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

A repository can be found at [BioanApp/bioan-server Github Repository](https://github.com/BioanApp/bioan-server/blob/feature/auth/auth/index.js) under the "feature/auth" branch.

Am I doing something wrong here? There are other examples out there where they use the `import passport from 'passport'` syntax, and even using `require('passport')` provides the same error.